# How do I remove nested object from an object in CakePHP?

Tags: php, json, cakephp, object, nested

CakePHP API returns result like this:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "themes": [
        {
            "Theme": {
                "id": "20",
                "user_id": "50",
                "name": "dwdwdw",
                "language_code_from": "cz",
                "language_code_to": "en",
                "type": "CUSTOM",
                "created": "2014-10-19 15:36:05",
                "count_of_cards": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to ask, how can in remove nested **Theme** object to get result like this?:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "themes": [
        {
                "id": "20",
                "user_id": "50",
                "name": "dwdwdw",
                "language_code_from": "cz",
                "language_code_to": "en",
                "type": "CUSTOM",
                "created": "2014-10-19 15:36:05",
                "count_of_cards": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my CakePHP code:

```
$this->Theme->recursive = -1;
                        // GET USER ID
                        $themeData['user_id'] = $isSessionValid;
                        // GET ALL THEMES RELATED TO USER
                        $foundThemes = $this->Theme->find('all', array(
                                'conditions' => array(
                                    'Theme.user_id' => $themeData['user_id'])
                            )
                        );
                        $themes = array();
                        // FOREACH THEMES AND GET COUNT FOR CARDS FOR EACH THEME
                        foreach($foundThemes as $foundTheme) {
                            // GET COUNT OF QUESTIONS FOR ACTUAL THEME
                            $countOfCards = $this->Theme->Card->find('count', array(
                                'conditions' => array(
                                    'Card.theme_id' => $foundTheme['Theme']['id'])
                                )
                            );
                            // APPEND TO ACTUAL ARRAY
                            $foundTheme['Theme']['count_of_cards'] = $countOfCards;
                            array_push($themes,$foundTheme);
                        }

                        // SET SUCCESS RESPOSNSE
                        $this->set(array(
                            'status' => 'OK',
                            'themes' => $themes,
                            '_serialize' => array(
                                'status',
                                'themes',
                            )
                        ));
```

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you saying you don't like the value `set` is returning to your view? If so - did you try changing the _themes_ key to `'themes' => $themes['Theme']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate CakePHP's array formats using its built in `Hash` utility: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash

What I would do would be to flatten the results:

```
$results = Hash::flatten($results);
```

Your data array will end up as a single dimensional array looking like this:

```
$results = array(
    'status' => 'OK'
     'themes.0.Theme.id' => 20,
     ...
     'themes.1.Theme.id' => 21,
     ...
);
```

You can then use string replace to remove "Theme" from your keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($results);
$keys = str_replace('Theme.', '', $keys);
```

Then you can use Hash::expand to get your original array, now formatted how you want:

```
$results = Hash::expand(array_combine($keys, array_values($results)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think CakePHP supports this. if you want to do this with an easy way check the Set Utility.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html

Comment: Could you please provide some Example? There is a lot of set function usages.

Comment: `$foundThemes = Set::classicExtract($tasks, '{n}.Theme');`

is this what you need;